# Further verify result using MOQ

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I have the following code

```
public bool IsUnitAvailable()
        {
            this.isUnitAvailable = false;
                if(isUnitAvailable == false)
                {
                    var exception = new Exception("Unit Unavailable");
                    exception.Data.Add("Quotation","1234567");
                    exception.Data.Add("propertyDate", "2016-10-10");                        this.GetElmahExtensionWrapper().LogToElmah(exception);
                }
            }    
            return this.isUnitAvailable;
        }
```

and the following unit test.

```
[TestMethod]    
    public void WhenUnitIsNotAvailableExceptionShouldBeLoggedInElmahTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        var iPricingServiceMock = new Mock<IPricingService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        iPricingServiceMock.Setup(
            counter => counter.IsUnitAvailableOn(It.IsAny<Unit>(),It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Returns(false);

        var mockElmahExtensionWrapper = TestHelper.mk.GetMock<IElmahExtensionWrapper>();

        // act
        var quotation = new Quotation();
        quotation.SetElmahExtensionWrapper(mockElmahExtensionWrapper.Object);
        quotation.IsUnitAvailable();

        //assert
        mockElmahExtensionWrapper.Verify(counter => counter.LogToElmah(It.IsAny<Exception>()), Times.Exactly(1));
//change the test to verify that the exception that was logged had 2 Data properties?
    }
```

The unit test is working. How can I change the test to verify that the exception that was logged had 2 Data properties? Changing the code to the following throws a "Cannot resolve symbol Data property" error.

```
mockElmahExtensionWrapper.Verify
                (
                    counter => counter.LogToElmah
                    (
                        It.IsAny<Exception>(ex=>ex.Data.Count == 2)
                    ), 
                    Times.Exactly(1) 
                );
```

[image]

Comment: You can't do that with `It.IsAny<T>`, you have to use `It.Is<T>`

Comment: Thank you @AD.Net. This works. I wish I could mark the comment as the correct answer.

Comment: I didn't add as answer because the answer does do the same thing with `It.Is<>` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the verification to something like:

```
 mockElmahExtensionWrapper.Verify(counter => counter.LogToElmah(It.Is<TraceException>(ex => ex.Data["Quotation"] == "1234567" && ex.Data["propertyDate"] == "2016-10-10"), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Comment: I had tried something similar but I get a "cannot resolve symbol Data" error.

Comment: I do not know what is the API of TraceException. However the error is strinave because you are using "Data" in your code.

Comment: I have changed the question above to use a Exception instead of a TraceException. Data is a property for Exception class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Read my answer again: it should it It.Is<>, not It.IsAny<>. Please mark my asnwer as the correct :)

Comment: Oh I am sorry @Pellared. You are right. I missed the It.Is part. I have marked the answer as the correct answer.